# could not open relation with OID 133630413

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables

Iam using Postgresql 11.
But on testing few functions getting

> error XX000: could not open relation with OID 133630413 .

It worked fine in Development environment,but failing in production .
Any inputs appreciated.
One of the functions worked fine, when we commented the below code called at the end o the function.

```
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tt_LOCALRISKVALUES CASCADE;
   --DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tt_LEGALRISKVALUES CASCADE;
   --DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tt_CLIENTALLOWEDRDID CASCADE;
```

But now frequently getting for other functions too..ANy quick fix that can be done ?

Comment: Could you also post the function that is throwing this exception? Is it possible that different functions use the same temporary table or at least create temporary tables with the same name?

Comment: thanks @JimJones for your response...Actually when the above code was commented for one of the functions ,it worked well,now the error populated for  other functions also.Looking for a any generic solutions ....

Comment: The error message says that the database is trying to open an object that no longer exists, and since you're dealing with drop table cascade statements I suspect you're deleting things the functions still need ... hard to tell without seeing the functions and knowing the use case, but certainly the SO postgres experts will give you a better direction. Cheers

Comment: We need the (ideally simplified) function code to reproduce the error.